# How to change the style of numbers inside a cell?

Tags: css, html

trying to change the style of a number inside a cell without also changing the style of the cell itself.

i'm learning web developing and someone suggested creating a game would be a good idea. I'm trying to create a Sudoku game, with the regular style and set up. it's looking the way i want it to except for i can't change the color of the numbers inside the cells without also changing the color of the cell itself. I have the styling in a separate css file and tried making changes to it and also adding  to the html file but i can't get it to work. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

here's the html

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assignment 1.css">
 <title>sudoku</title>
</head>
 <table>
  <colgroup><col><col><col>
  <colgroup><col><col><col>
  <colgroup><col><col><col>

  <tbody>
  <tr> <td>1 <td>  <td>3 <td>6 <td>  <td>4 <td>7 <td>  <td>9
  <tr> <td>  <td>2 <td>  <td>  <td>9 <td>  <td>  <td>1 <td>
  <tr> <td>7 <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>6
  <tbody>
  <tr> <td>2 <td>  <td>4 <td>  <td>3 <td>  <td>9 <td>  <td>8
  <tr> <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>
  <tr> <td>5 <td>  <td>  <td>9 <td>  <td>7 <td>  <td>  <td>1
  <tbody>
  <tr> <td>6 <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>5 <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>2
  <tr> <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>7 <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>
  <tr> <td>9 <td>  <td>  <td>8 <td>  <td>2 <td>  <td>  <td>5
```

and the css

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Palatino linotype, sans- 
serif; }
colgroup, tbody { border: solid medium;}
td { border: solid thin; height: 1.4em; width: 1.4em; text-align: center; 
padding: 0; }
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku#/media/File:Sudoku_Puzzle_by_L2G-20050714_solution_standardized_layout.svg

i want the look to be similar to this, where the constant numbers are a different color.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the **tbody**, **tr** and **td** tags. To learn more about tables : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 0):

I have tried two options.

1. Red color text covered with th instead of td
2. Blue color td has a class and styled according to it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
table {
 font-size: 50px;
 background: #000;
}
table table {
 background: #fff;
}
table table td, table table th {
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
table table th {
 color: red;
}
table table td.blue{color:blue;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td width="200"><table width="100%" height="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">1</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">2</td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" class="blue">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">4</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle" class="blue">5</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">7</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">8</th>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">9</th>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
    <td width="200"><table width="100%" height="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">1</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">2</td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">4</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">5</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">7</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">8</th>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">9</th>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
    <td width="200"><table width="100%" height="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">1</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">2</td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">4</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">5</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">7</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">8</th>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">9</th>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" height="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">1</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">2</td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">4</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">5</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">7</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">8</th>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">9</th>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
    <td><table width="100%" height="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">1</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">2</td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">4</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">5</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">7</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">8</th>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">9</th>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
    <td><table width="100%" height="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">1</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" class="blue">2</td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">4</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">5</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">7</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">8</th>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">9</th>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" height="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">1</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">2</td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">4</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">5</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">7</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">8</th>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">9</th>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
    <td><table width="100%" height="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">1</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" class="blue">2</td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" class="blue">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" class="blue">4</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">5</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" class="blue">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">7</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">8</th>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">9</th>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
    <td><table width="100%" height="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">1</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">2</td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">4</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">5</th>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">7</td>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">8</th>
          <th align="center" valign="middle">9</th>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```